# can not connect to clearDBmySQL from django

Tags: django, heroku, cleardb

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'tajaratdatabase',
        'USER': '', #here I am using my username
        'PASSWORD':'', #here I am using my password
        'HOST':'us-cdbr-east-04.cleardb.com',
        'PORT':'3306',
    }
}
```

I f I use the same credentials on MySQLworkbench my connection is successfully established but if I try to connect from my terminal and run command `python manage.py makemigrations` I got an error

django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1044, "Access denied for user 'bf76.....'@'%' to database 'tajaratdatabase'")

how can I remove this error and can make my connection successful

Answer (score -2):

make sure you are using the correct details for your database to connect